# error Bad Request in WCF using basichttpBinding with transfermode of streamed

Tags: c#, wcf

Im Having a problem consuming my WCF service, first i tried to consume my wcf without adding service reference, and i use channelfactory to consume it when i use basichttpbinding and transfermode of buffered it works fine but when i use streamed as transfermode it give error Bad Request

Here's where i call my service please take a look thanks in advance

```
public static BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding()
    {
        BasicHttpBinding BasicHttpBinding_IService1 = new BasicHttpBinding();
        BasicHttpBinding_IService1.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.Parse("00:01:00");
        BasicHttpBinding_IService1.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.Parse("00:01:00");
        BasicHttpBinding_IService1.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.Parse("00:10:00");
        BasicHttpBinding_IService1.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.Parse("00:01:00");
        BasicHttpBinding_IService1.AllowCookies = false;
        BasicHttpBinding_IService1.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
        BasicHttpBinding_IService1.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
        BasicHttpBinding_IService1.MaxBufferSize = 2147483646;
        BasicHttpBinding_IService1.MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288;
        BasicHttpBinding_IService1.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483646;
        BasicHttpBinding_IService1.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text;
        BasicHttpBinding_IService1.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
        BasicHttpBinding_IService1.TextEncoding = UTF8Encoding.UTF8;
        BasicHttpBinding_IService1.TransferMode = TransferMode.Streamed;


        return BasicHttpBinding_IService1;
    }

    public static EndpointAddress endPointAddress()
    {
        EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new   EndpointAddress("http://localhost:5409/IService.svc");

        return endpointAddress;
    }


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        ChannelFactory<IService> myChannelFactory = null;
        myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(basicHttpBinding(), endPointAddress());
        IService client =  myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
        MessageBox.Show(client.GetData(1));
    }
```

Comment: According to your code, you're using Buffered, not Streamed, transfer mode. Maybe this is the "good" code that works. If I had this problem, I'd make sure the host and client software agree on the mode you're using. I've tried streamed in the past and, while it's good on server memory usage, it's a complete pain in the a$$ to get running properly. Unless you have serious memory constraints on your project, forget about streaming.

Comment: thanks for yor response, i need to use streamed for large file download

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [WCF Diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details?

Comment: @PetarVučetin ill check the link thanks, anyways is there a service model i can use instead of basichttpbinding where i can download large file?

Comment: Is your scenario Intranet or Internet? Do you control client and the server?

Comment: How is the service being hosted?

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys i finally figure it out i just need to put it to IIS thanks

Comment: So you were using the development server after all?

Comment: @Angelo: I'm a bit confused. You state in the comment to my answer that you were hosting in IIS, yet 2 minutes later you state that you fixed it by hosting in IIS. It sounds like you were using the development server the whole time and my tip solved your problem, but if this is not the case then could you elaborate on what you did exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TransferMode` of `Streamed` is not supported by the ASP.NET development server.

Use IIS or Self-Host the WCF Service to get around it.